# getting Cannot GET / while using Grunt Connect

Tags: angularjs, node.js, gruntjs

while running server using grunt, am getting error as Cannot GET /

**server.js**

```
    var express = require('express');

    var app = express();
    var port = process.env.PORT || 2323;

    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/server'));
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

    app.get('/', function(req, res){
        res.sendfile('./server/views/index.html');
    });

    app.listen(port, function(){
        console.log('server is running on ' + port);
    });
```

**Gruntfile.js**

```
module.exports = function(grunt){

    var modRewrite = require('connect-modrewrite');
    var serveStatic = require('serve-static');

    grunt.initConfig({

        connect: {
            server: {
                options: {
                    port: 2323,
                    base: 'views',
                    keepalive: true,
                    livereload: 35729,
                    hostname: 'localhost',
                    open: true,
                    middleware: function (connect) {
                        return [
                                    modRewrite(['^[^\\.]*$ /index.html [L]']),
                                    connect().use('/', serveStatic('/views'))
                                ];
                            }
                   }
            }
        }

        // configure connect



    });

    //load nodemon
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-connect');

    //register the nodemon task when we run grunt
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['connect:server']);

};
```

And i don't know whether my grunt-file code is right or wrong 
Actually am new grunt , i don't know what to do, am getting **Cannot GET /** this error while running grunt.

Answer (score 0):

You just have an error in the setup of the connect server running in Grunt:

```
connect().use('/', serveStatic('/views'))
```

should be

```
connect().use('/', serveStatic('./server/views'))
```

Comment: You need to setup a connect server in the Gruntfile, if you want it to behave like server.js. You probably are better off using [grunt-express](https://github.com/blai/grunt-express) since it looks like you are more accustomed to express.